# Proof that $M = \left\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+3z^3 = xy + 6z^{\frac{1}{3}}, z \neq 0\right\}$ is manifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Proof that $$M = \left\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+3z^3 = xy + 6z^{\frac{1}{3}}, z \neq 0\right\}$$ is differentiable manifold.

The problem is that when $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+3z^3 - xy - 6z^{\frac{1}{3}}$, then $[\partial_x g,\partial_y g,\partial_z g]=[0,0,0]$ in $(0,0,z)$ for some $z$. I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Did you also check if said points $(0,0,z)$ also satisfy $3z^3=6z^{1/3}$?

Comment: (silly of me to ask: of course they do)

Comment: Umm... so we have $f(z)=g(0,0,z)=3z^2-6z^{1/3}$. $f'(z)=0$ when $z=\frac{2^{3/8}}{3^{3/4}}$ but $3z^3=6z^{1/3}$ when $z=2^{3/8}$ so after all problematic point isn't a possibility?

Comment: Actually, my second comment was wrong. I had a typo in my calculations. Remember that the implicit function theorem holds when the function has no singular points **on the level set you are considering**. For instance, $S^1=\{x^2+y^2=1\}$ is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$ because the singular point of $x^2+y^2-1$ (which is $(0,0)$) does not lie in it.

Comment: In your case, you can see it like this: being an embedded submanifold is a transitive property, i.e. if $M$ is an embedded submanifold of $N$ and $N$ is an embedded submanifold of $T$, then $M$ is an embedded submanifold of $T$. In your case, you are applying this fact with $T=\Bbb R^3$ and $$N=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}\,:\, \nabla g(x,y,z)\ne 0\right\}$$ which is an open subset of $\Bbb R^3$ because $\nabla g:\Bbb R^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}\to\Bbb R^3$ is continuous. Open subsets of a manifold are embedded submanifolds.